# Multiple location on Bing Map

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, maps, bing-maps

I have a generic list of addresses with Lat and Lng values in asp.net webform application. How can i show them on BingMap?

List is saved in session and there is a button called 'Map' which opens a new window and suppose to  show all the locations (i think its called pin points) on bing map.

What is the best way to achieve this? Client side or server side?

I have gone through msdn but all the examples are client side related but i am thinking about doing it at runtime from code behind page.

Comment: Just came across http://deepak-sharma.net/2013/02/08/how-to-add-pushpins-to-a-bing-map-from-database-using-asp-dot-net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the data in the client then showing it on the map using client side code would be the easiest option. Rather than opening a new window I would recommend just showing a panel above the rest of the page using a div, similar to the modal dialog from jQuery UI. By doing this you will be able to use a single map to view locations. That way if a user presses the map button, then presses it again, only one map will ever be opened, but the data will change to what ever data is in the client. The benefit of this is that the more you can reuse a map, the less times you need to load a new one which will make things slightly faster, and will also reduce the number of transactions your application creates which will keep the costs down.

If you have the data in JavaScript, displaying it on Bing Maps is really easy. Here is a simple document that shows how to add a map and pushpins to a webpage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427604.aspx Simply loop through your data and use the lat/lon values to create pushpins. If you number your data in a list you can easily display that number on the pushpin by using the text property in the pushpin options. Here is an example: http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#Pushpins4

Comment: I have data at server side and it is also available in session. So i think i won't be able to do it at client side.

Comment: Pass the data to the client. Doing it server side isn't really an option.